# Tkinter interactive and dynamic GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-2.x

I am currently coding a little Python script for a colleague of mine which should give the framework for his PhD defense challenge, e.g. little tasks and questions he has to answer. The script itself should guide him through his challenges and give those tasks, introductions, etc.

I am currently using Tkinter for that purpose. Principally, I want to have a canvas/part of the screen, where text and introductions pop up like in the example shown below.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time


global_delay =150
counter = 0
delay = global_delay

def display_text():
  global num_letters 
  global global_text  
  global label   
  text = global_text[counter]
  num_letters = len(text) - 1
  old_text = label.cget("text")+'\n'
  def display():
    global num_letters
    global counter
    global global_delay
    global delay
    if delay == 0:
        user_text = ''
        com_text = '               '
    else:
        user_text = 'user@hlrdbb4 ~ '
        com_text = ''
    print_text = old_text + user_text + str(text[1:len(text) - num_letters])+(num_letters+50-len(text))*' ' + com_text
    label.config(text=print_text)
    label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
    num_letters-=1
    if num_letters>=0:
        label.after(delay, display)
    elif counter<len(global_text)-1:
        counter += 1
        if global_text[counter][0] == 'o':
            delay = 0
        if global_text[counter][0] == 'i':
            delay = global_delay
        label.after(global_delay*10, display_text)

display()


root = tk.Tk()

w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))


root.title("PhD")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green", bg='black', height=h, width=w, anchor=tk.NW)
label.pack()

global_text=['icd E:\dbb\ ','oChange directory to E:\dbb\ ','iget_PhD.exe','oError file not found','iget_PhD.exe','oError file not found','iget_PhD.exe','oExecuting get_PhD.exe','oHere are your introductions...']
display_text()


root.mainloop()
```

The other side of the GUI should display the corresponding minigames, e.g. a dynamically changing noise plot for which he has to put in some numbers to see a decent signal. As you can see I am currently using the after-method at the moment to display the text, but I can't figure out, how to incorporate such games or how the script could wait for his (keyboard) input to continue.

Could anyone help me here a bit?

Comment: The  input() function waits for user input, you can store the input in a variable

Comment: Using input() would force the user to use console, while this is an GUI application.

Comment: GUIs don't work the way you're probably used to programming, where the program displays something and then waits for user input, reacts to it, then displays something else and again awaits user input, etc. They are "event-driven" which means they define and display "widgets", some of which can generate events, like when they are clicked. In such cases, the widget will have a callback function that gets called when that happens. It's a whole different programming paradigm. That's said, you're going to need to design some kind of framework to accomplish what you want to do—a very tall order.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a keyboard input (in this case enter) or a tkinter button, to use the input of an Entry widget. You execute a function with it (in this case callback). You continue your program if you get the desired input.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

def callback(*args):
    print (e.get())

e.bind("<Return>",callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Some good reading material and extra explanation:
[Tkinter Confirmation buttons and game GUI (splice(?))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569151/tkinter-confirmation-buttons-and-game-gui-splice)